# How can I open application from EKEvent

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, calendar

Is there any way with which we can open our application when some event in calendar is triggered.
What this actually means is, suppose I create and EKEvent and `addAlarm:` for this event. Now what I want is when this alarm is triggered I want my application to open, there is no problem is an alert show where user has option like, **view** & **cancel**. and when he/she selects **view** my applications opens, just `like local OR push notification`.

Comment: Did you manage to find anything regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

In view event, display a hyperlink for your application.

Tapping on that link can open your application.

I guess so... Not sure about this...

Answer (score 0):

You can open the event by using Apple Script

See [Calendar Scripting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/CalendarScriptingGuide/Calendar-RevealanEvent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016646-CH96-SW3)

```
   tell application "Calendar"
    tell calendar "Project Calendar"
        show (first event where its summary = "Important Meeting!")
    end tell
   end tell
```